# DOM is not working

Tags: javascript, dom, vbscript

I am trying to enter value in textbox(located in iFrame) and click on button using DOM(.vbs file)

Steps:
1.Enter UserName value in Textbox
2.Click on Process Button
3.it will return list of records enter code here

problem is,after i enter UserName value in Textbox, 
javascript is not triggering hence after clicking on button i am getting No record found.
if i enter manually value in textbox,and run vb script for clicking button alone,its returning records.
it seems some problem with after entering value in textbox.
below is my code that i am running as .vbs file,

```
set oTB=IE.iFrame.contentDocument.getElementByID("textboxID")
oTB.value="UserName"
set oBtn=IE.iFrame.contentDocument.getElementByID("buttonID")
oBtn.click
```

unfortunatlly i cant copy the html file but almost similer to below one,

```
<input> id="textboxID" onkeyup="autocomplete(textboxID)" onclick="autocomplete(textboxID)" </input>

<button> id="buttonID" </button>
```

please let me know where i am making mistake with DOM.

Comment: I'd ensure that you HTML attributes are inside you tags for starters.

Comment: id and other stuff goes inside the tag like so:
`<button id="buttonID">  </button>`

Answer (score 1):

The attributes must be part of the HTML tags. Additionally, pass `this` to the `autocomplete` function to pass a reference of the input element:

```
<input id="textboxID" onkeyup="autocomplete(this)" onclick="autocomplete(this)"/>

<button id="buttonID">my button</button>
```